# jboss/tomcat tld cache invalidation

Tags: caching, tomcat, jboss, tld

I have a jboss application with some ears. There's war inside ear and there's file monitor.tld inside WEB-INF folder of war.

There's some tag definitions inside the monitor.tld. I added my custom tag definition in this file, and restarted jsboss. After that, when I use my tag in jsp I get error:

```
2011-04-23 16:38:31,829 INFO  [STDOUT] 2011-04-23 16:38:31,761 [http-0.0.0.0-8080-4] ERROR [] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/Monitor].[jsp] - Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /tiles/layout/wizardLayout.jsp(140,4) No tag "wizardNavEx" defined in tag library imported with prefix "mon"
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseCustomTag(Parser.java:1213)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1449)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:133)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:216)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:103)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:167)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:306)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:286)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:273)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:566)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:316)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:336)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:292)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.doForward(TilesRequestProcessor.java:295)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processTilesDefinition(TilesRequestProcessor.java:271)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesRequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(TilesRequestProcessor.java:332)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:232)
...
```

So, my custom tag `wizardNavEx` doesn't work, but `wizardNav` defined in monitor.tld a couple of lines above works fine.

I think the problem is tomcat/jboss cached previous version of monitor.tld in someplace. How can I clear that caches? Any ideas?

Versions:

X-Powered-By='Servlet 2.4; JBoss-4.2.2.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_2_GA date=200710221139)/Tomcat-5.5'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that another monitor.tld existed inside one of jar files.